# Import workflows Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to create standard pipelines for my products build with Cloud Build and I would like to store them in a central location, so when I need to do a modify I just need to it in one place and not in all the products.

Is there a way to be able to import workflows in Cloud Build from another central repository?

Something like:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/includes.html or https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/sharing-workflows-with-your-organization

Thank you,

Comment: I found this https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudbuild-integration-testing/blob/master/cloudbuild.meta.yaml which could work has workaround but I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Did you consider integration with [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/integrating-with-cloud-build)?
Is it suitable for you?

Comment: Hi @FaridShumbar could be but I don't see the advantage. How that resolve the issue?

Comment: You can integrate Cloud Build with source repositories, and mirror their GitHub repo so that, for example, when an update is done in a branch on GitHub, it is automatically replicated to Cloud source repos and from there it triggers the build of the app without any manual involvement

Comment: Hi @Farid , thanks for your comment but you didn't understand well my question. I left an example of GitLab and Jenkins of what I'm trying to achieve. What you proposed , you don't need to use Google Cloud Repo service , it also works from GitHub (event the integration is better). What I'm trying to do is to extend pipelines. But I finally discharge to use Cloud Build.

Comment: Hi @DaniLou, could you explain why you are discharged the use of Cloud build? This is to better understand the reasoning and to try explaining in a better way the reason for using the tool. Thanks